# GlobalAveragePooling2D() - AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I cannot get GlobalAveragePooling2D to work when I try to append it to InceptionV3. Does anyone see what im doing wrong? I can get GlobalMaxPooling2D to work.

```
inceptModel = InceptionV3(include_top=False, input_shape= (162,243, 3))
x = inceptModel.outputs
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
```

results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 617, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/layers/pooling.py", line 540, in call
    return K.mean(inputs, axis=[1, 2])
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1362, in mean
    if x.dtype.base_dtype == tf.bool:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

but

```
GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)
```

works fine. Does anyone have an idea?

Versions:

```
import keras; print(keras.__version__)
2.1.3

import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)
1.2.1
```

Comment: Use outputs[0], outputs is a list of outputs.

Comment: output is a list of 1 Tensor after initializing InceptionV3:

[<tf.Tensor 'mixed10_1/concat:0' shape=(?, 8, 13, 2048) dtype=float32>]

Comment: Thanks! Using x = inceptModel.output instead of outputs worked.